Better way to search for generic Task<T> expression
I am on a roslyn analyzer that can handle async Task<T> boxing to an object variable like:
int GetValue() => ...

void Print(object value) => Console.WriteLine(value);

void Main() {
  Print(GetValue());
}

if you change:
-int GetValue() => ...
+Task<int> GetValue() => ...

the analyzer should throw a warning.
I am actually at the very end of the coding and just want to optimize my code on that certain position:
I have got a IsGenericTaskType Method, were the ITypeSymbol that is transferred to it gets analyzed for being System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1 but by string-comparison what I actually don't like.
ChatGPTs answer:
type as INamedTypeSymbol)?.ConstructedFrom.SpecialType == SpecialType.System_Threading_Tasks_Task_T;

but I cannot access SpecialType.System_Threading_Tasks_Task_T due to CS1061..
Is there any possible way to compare my type symbol without using strings?

Don't make us look up error codes. :/

What does randomly generated text have to do with anything and why should it work at all? The problem isn't boxing anyway, it's the conversion to an asynchronous operation. You already get a warning for async operations that don't get awaited.

There's no such member on SpecialType: ChatGPT is making stuff up. https://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/SpecialType.cs,23. You can either check MetadataName against a string (which is fine), or fetch an ISymbol for Task from the compilation (again by metadata name) and compare against that

There's no such thing as SpecialType.System_Threading_Tasks_Task_T. That's just random text

Do not ask GPT for code. It does not know how to code. It does not even know that it is supposed to code. It doesn't know what code is, what it is supposed to do or if what it suggests to you makes any sense. It will happily present you with utter BS and sound so confident and convincing like a politician during election time.

What's the actual problem you want to detect? There's already a warning for unawaited async tasks in async methods and the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers analyzer adds a check (VSTHRD110) for unawaited tasks in synchronous methods. The package is open source so you can inspect the analyzer code and modify it to do what you want.

@PanagiotisKanavos Reading the question, OP wants to raise a warning when a box happens. That includes an implicit box because a value type is returned from a method which returns a Task<ReferenceType>

@canton7 with int GetValue that would generate a compilation error, not boxing. The method would have to be async Task<int> GetValue to result in a conversion to a Task (again not boxing) but that would also result in a warning if there was no await in the async method.

@PanagiotisKanavos I'm going to assume they missed an await in the example, and it should be Print(await GetValue()). That will result in the int being boxed

@canton7 there was a performance analyzer for this in the Roslyn Clr Heap Allocation Analyzer before the original Roslyn analyzers got reorganized

There are a couple of boxing analyzers in dotnet/roslyn-analyzers, packaged into Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.PerformanceSensitiveAnalyzers.

Omitting await would result in a compilation error though, so the question is still unclear. The only thing that doesn't raise an error is async Task<int> GetValue() => 3; which raises the more relevant CS1998 - the async method runs synchronously because there's no await.
